# Error con $text en mongodb

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Estuve leyendo la documentacion sobre el operador $text en mongo db y el ejemplo

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } ) se ejecuta correctamente.
```

A la hora de cambiar de colección e introducir lo que deseo buscar me salta el siguiente error

```
Stacktrace: 
|_/ java.lang.Exception: [ex01.libros@biblodb [replica set: atlas-uf29n0-shard-0]] Database error!
|____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 27 and error message 'text index required for $text query' on server cluster0-shard-00-02.8oeno.mongodb.net:27017
```

En la coleccion en la que quiero hacer el ejemplo que me da el error existe el campo "título" con documentos llamados química por lo que supuse que me tenía que arrojar algún resultado pero no es así. Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer consultas del tipo $text primero se tiene que crear un índice en el que se define que campo va a ser en el que se va a realizar ese tipo de consulta. Por lo que en esta coleccion al ser el campo "título" al que se le quiere aplicar la consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
db.libros.createIndex({título:"text"})
```

por lo que podemos verificar en la consola que se ejecuta la operación.

Ahora si hacemos la consulta en la que se menciona el error en la pregunta:

```
db.libros.find( { $text: { $search: "quimica" } } )
```

nos muestra los resultados que coinciden con esa búsqueda

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60adc8b1f57b1d4c2b00c2e1"), 
    "título" : "Química", 
    "Autor" : [
        "Raymond Chang", 
        "Kenneth Goldsby"
    ], 
    "Edicion" : "11va", 
    "Categoría" : "Química", 
    "registro" : 3.0, 
    "cantidad" : 3.0, 
    "en prestamo" : 0.0, 
    "disponibles" : 3.0, 
    "veces prestado" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60adc8b1f57b1d4c2b00c2e0"), 
    "título" : "Química", 
    "Autor" : [
        "Raymond Chang", 
        "Kenneth Goldsby"
    ], 
    "Edicion" : "12va", 
    "Categoría" : "Química", 
    "registro" : 2.0, 
    "cantidad" : 5.0, 
    "en prestamo" : 1.0, 
    "disponibles" : 4.0, 
    "veces prestado" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60adc9a6408965e33f808af3"), 
    "título" : "Química Cuántica", 
    "Autor" : "Ira N. Levine", 
    "Edicion" : "6ta", 
    "Categoría" : "Química", 
    "registro" : 1.0, 
    "cantidad" : 3.0, 
    "en prestamo" : 0.0, 
    "disponibles" : 3.0, 
    "veces prestado" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60adc8b1f57b1d4c2b00c2e2"), 
    "título" : "Introducción a La Termodinámica en Ingeniería Química", 
    "Autor" : "H. C. Van Ness", 
    "Edicion" : "7ma", 
    "Categoría" : "Termodinámica", 
    "registro" : 4.0, 
    "cantidad" : 4.0, 
    "en prestamo" : 1.0, 
    "disponibles" : 3.0, 
    "veces prestado" : NumberInt(1)
}
```